# My code is not working. Am I doing it right?

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

What I want to achieve is:

I will choose what column should I update, this is why I am experimenting on my  code but did not work and now I think I need some help.

```
Dim btnup="col1"
Dim btnval="1"
Try
    Dim mysqlconn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim conStr As String
    conStr = "Server=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=dnc_floor"
    mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection(conStr)
    mysqlconn.Open()
    Dim update As String
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    update = "Update floor set ='" & btnup & "'=btnval  where ID='" & Day & "'"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(update, mysqlconn)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim check As String = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Saved")
    mysqlconn.Close()
Catch ex As MySqlException
    MessageBox.Show("Check your connection with your database")
Finally
    mysqlconn.Dispose()
End Try
```

Comment: what code is not running or what is the exception

Comment: you password is missing

Comment: Can you connect successfully to MySQL?  Is there any error output?  Your query is prone to SQL injection, by the way.  You should use a prepared statement.

Comment: Are you getting error(s)? if yes, when (compiling, executing, attempting to perform the update....)?

Comment: and please use parameter instead of where ID='" & Day & "'"

Comment: i think it should be  update = "Update floor set btnval= '" & btnup & "' where ID='" & Day & "'"

Comment: problem is in update query have you run it manually in mysql editor

Comment: no i didn't set any password to the database because that was only a testing. the error that i get was "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspond to your MariaDB server version  for the right syntax to  use  near "btn1'='1' where ID='1" at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update string is probably wrong. Maybe u think of that:

```
  update = "Update floor set " & btnup & " ='" & btnval & "'  where ID= '" & Day & "'"
```

Comment: Bad suggestion, beware of injection

Comment: @un-lucky yup I considered that and updated my code.